# matlab all sheets gather

Tags: matlab, xls

i have a lots of excel files in same directory...each of the excel file has several sheets inside...

May i know how to gather all sheets from all the excel files into new excel file?

```
names=dir('*.xls');
names={names.name};
output='out.xls';
for i=1:length(names)
  z = xlsread(names{i});
xlswrite(output,z);
end
```

keep erroring..anyone can help?!

Comment: Here is a good reference to start: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-17PWC/?solution=1-17PWC . Also StackOverflow has a number of questions about manipulating Excel files in MATLAB (search is your friend)

Comment: i have try to write the code and paste it in the question..but keep error..i have no idea why..

Comment: It would help to post the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation:

```
%# get all XLS files in source directory
dirName = '.\in';
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.xls') );
files = {files.name}';                      %'

%# for each input file
for i=1:numel(files)
    fname = fullfile(dirName, files{i});    %# absolute-path filename
    [~,f] = fileparts(fname);               %# used to name sheets in output

    %# loop over each sheet in input file
    [~,sheets] = xlsfinfo(fname);
    for s=1:numel(sheets)
        %# read content
        [~,~,rawData] = xlsread(fname, sheets{s});

        %# write to output file as new sheet
        xlswrite('out.xls', rawData, [f '_' sheets{s}]);
    end
end
```